# The exact value of csc -420 degrees (Find the exact value of each trigonometric funtion)

Tags: trigonometry

I'am very confused, I have looked all over google and I can not find out how too do this problem. 
I have the answer its number 14 since our teacher gives us the answer but we need to show work.[image]

I understood number 13 it was $\sec -210^\circ$, but I can't figure out how too do #14. How can it be $-2 \sqrt{3}/ 3$? I just can't figure this problem out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The problem is $\csc -420^\circ$.

Comment: hint: $\csc x = \csc (x+360^\circ)= \csc (x+360^\circ+360^\circ)=\dots$

Answer (score 1):

$$\csc(-420^\circ)=-\csc 420^\circ=-\csc 60^\circ=-\frac{2\sqrt3}{2}$$

Comment: FYI: when working in degrees, you can append a degree-symbol as a subscript by writing 420^\circ. E.g., $420^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\csc(-420^\circ)= -\csc(420^\circ) \text{ since  cosecant  is  an  odd  function.  Thus}\\
-\csc(420^\circ) = -\csc(60^\circ) = -\frac{1}{\sin(60^\circ)} = -\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$

Comment: okay I know how you got the 60 but where did you get the radical 3/2?

Comment: From the unit circle.  At $60^\circ$, sine has has value of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: Think about the $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle.